# Rails returns incorrect MIME type for json api request (only in test)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mime

In my app I dynamically render javascript file which is requested by an external widget. Everything works nice in development env, but when I test, appears error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/widget_init.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Why it appears only in test environment and how to set up manually MIME type 'text/javascript?

route:

```
  get 'widget_init', to: 'widget/root#init'
```

controller:

```
def init
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html

    format.js { render 'init' }
  end
end
```

UPD: my test if it may help you:

```
scenario 'opens widget if webpage id and token are valid', js: true do
  webpage.url = 'http://localhost:3000/test_widget/with_script'
  webpage.save
  webpage.reload

  visit workspace_webpage_path(webpage)
  find('#open_webpage_button').click
  #here should open a widget
  expect(page).to have_selector('#follower_widget__script')
  expect(page).to have_selector('#follower_widget__root')
end
```

Comment: adding mime type manually does not help:       format.js { render 'init', mime_type: Mime::Type.lookup("text/javascript") }

Comment: May you show your test?

Comment: Hi @kunashir! I updated description.

Comment: the main mystery is that this error message appears only when I run rspec tests.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, the issue was in Chrome which opened a new tab with improper information (for example, user not logged in although I logged it in before in the same test).